# How to convert CString to byte [] array?

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, type-conversion

I am trying to convert `CString` to `byte []` array in Visual Studio MFC. Please see the code below.

```
CString str_text;
GetDlgItemText(IDC_KEY_TEXT, str_text);
```

1. `BYTE A[] = "hi I love stackoverflow";`
2. `BYTE A[] = str_text;`

Here, BYTE A [] is a byte array.

Regardless of `CString` and `GetDlgItemText` function, if I do only (1) my program does well. 
But  If you type CString(str_text)(2) instead of "hi I love stackoverflow" I have a error. That's error is "it couldn't convert CString to byte array". 
I would like to convert `CString` to byte array. Please tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: You can get a pointer to the string wrapped by `CString` (see e.g. [`GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=vs-2017#getstring)). Therefore you very seldom need to copy the string to its own array.

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356815/conversion-of-cstring-to-byte

Comment: Probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you need a `BYTE` array at all? Besides that, you can only omit the array size, if the compiler can deduce the size at compile time (as is the case when constructing it from a string literal). We also don't know, what `CString` is for you. It could be `CStringA` or `CStringW`. If it is the former, you already have a `char` array by way of invoking `CString::GetString()`. If it is the latter, your specification is ambiguous. You'd have to also specify the endian type you need.

Comment: @swo: That's not a duplicate. The linked Q&A is asking about type conversions. This Q&A is (presumably) asking, how to create a copy and store it in a `BYTE` array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way of doing this. I assume you deal with Unicode strings:

```
CStringW str = L"Hello World";
// convert to UTF-8
CStringA utf8 = CW2A(str, CP_UTF8);
CByteArray Bytes;   
const size_t nBytes = sizeof(CStringA::XCHAR) * utf8.GetLength();
Bytes.SetSize( nBytes );
std::memcpy( Bytes.GetData(), static_cast<BYTE const*>utf8, nBytes );
```

Comment: That's *one* potential solution. Yet, nothing in the question is asking about converting the string to UTF-8. Besides, `sizeof(CStringA::XCHAR)` will *always* be 1. Leaving this out simplifies the code, and doesn't cause any distraction. Also, `(const BYTE*)(LPCSTR)` should be `static_cast<BYTE const*>(utf8.GetString())`. No need for all those C-style casts.

Comment: @llnspectable I agree about C-style casts. I've provided extended example just for educational purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail answer. I will definitely try to do it.